# Which Winlogon session is attached to the sound device?

Tags: windows-10, php, desktop-computer, session

I want to select and play music stored in my **Windows 10 Home PC** from mobile devices connected by home WiFi network.
There's an Apache webserver running on my PC as a service logged on *Local System account*.
Users can browse the home-web from their tablet at URL `http://192.168.1.10/Music/index.php`,
select a song or playlist and then they touch the button `[PLAY]`.

First I tried to launch the selected song on PC with PHP function [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
exec("\"C:\\Program Files\\mplayerc.exe\" /play /close \"$SelectedSong.mp3\"");
```

but this didn't work, the *mplayerc* (classic version of *Media Player* from older Windows) terminated immediately.
Apparently since it was launched in the context of Apache service (session Nr 0) and had no access to speakers,
which were dedicated to a different user currently logged on local desktop on my home PC.
Allowing service *Apache 2.4* to interact with desktop made no change.

I found a solution with [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) which allows *mplayerc.exe* to interact with the desktop of another user, if their session number is known:

```
$SessionNr=1;
exec("\"C:\\Program Files\\psexec.exe\" -i $SessionNr -u .\\MyName -p MyPwd \"C:\\Program Files\\mplayerc.exe\" /play /close \"$SelectedSong.mp3\"");
```

This works with fixed **$SessionNr=1** when *MyName* is logged on locally on the PC (revealing my credentionals in the PHP script is not a concern). Nonetheless, I would like my script to play with monitor switched off, when PC is freshly rebooted or awaken from hibernation, and regardless of who is logged on, if anyone.

**How can I find the ordinal number of Windows logon session to which is the desktop and sound device currently attached?**

I have tried to play "*ThreeSecondsOfSilence.mp3*" with *$SessionNr* varying from 0 to 9 and measuring the elapsed time (unattached desktop returns immediately) but this method was lengthy and unreliable. I guess the wanted information is burried somehwere in *Windows Registry* but I don't know where to search.

Comment: having the same issue, a service creates a process (createProcessAsUser) on user's session ,the sound works but on winlogon's session there is no sound.